# Один php скрипт: nginx возвращает 200, apache - 302

Tags: php, apache, nginx

Имеем следующий код:

```
<?php

header("Status: 200 OK");
header("Location: http://google.com");
var_dump(http_response_code());
```

Тестовая среда для запуска (docker-compose только для примера, если вам удобнее можно и без него, но результат идентичный): https://github.com/Mapteg34/nginx200_when_apache302

```
mapt@mpc test % curl -v 127.0.0.1:6091/test.php
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 6091 (#0)
> GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:6091
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Sat, 09 Jun 2018 12:18:03 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.36
< Status: 200 OK
< Location: http://google.com
< Content-Length: 9
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
int(302)
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact



mapt@mpc test % curl -v 127.0.0.1:6092/test.php
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 6092 (#0)
> GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:6092
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.13.7
< Date: Sat, 09 Jun 2018 12:18:08 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.36
< Location: http://google.com
< 
int(302)
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

В итоге получаем проблему (или все-таки что-то некорректно настроено?): apache возвращает 302 (и в целом это правильно), nginx возвращает 200 и location (и это не корректно).

Есть идеи как исправить это и заставить nginx (nginx.conf) возвращать на этом коде логичный 302, так же как апач (и это не проблема fpm, если посмотреть его логин он тоже отдает 302)?

---

Я понимая что пример наверное из разряда "сам проблему создал...". Но в реальности первую строчку (Status: 200 OK) выставляет CMS и я не могу это изменить. А дальше (Location: http://google.com) это уже мой код. Конечно я могу его поменять, например установив предварительно свой статус, или сделав header_remove(), но работать будет в данном месте, а есть другие модули, есть в конце концов части CMS, использующие ту же конструкцию. Все их поменять не получится (да и нельзя). Однако на Apache оно вполне работает и надо заставить его работать в рамках nginx.

Comment: здравый смысл подсказывает, что некорректно действует как раз программа apache — подменяет (видимо, благодаря непрошенному кэшированию) один из возвращаемых библиотекой php http-заголовков.

Comment: ещё здравый смысл подсказывает, что «место для удара молотком» — это программа php-fpm.

Comment: Здравый смысл подсказывает, что 200 и Location в одном ответе это мусор. Поэтому работает правило garbage in garbage out

Comment: @alexander-barakin, насколько я вижу апач отрабатывает весьма логично, по мануалу: при установке location код тоже должен меняться на 302, или я что-то упускаю?

Comment: программа *apache* у вас вообще не интерпретирует заголовок `status`. это видно по приведённому вами выводу программы *curl* — он просто передаётся клиенту «как есть». а программа *nginx* — интерпретирует. вполне возможно, что обе программы действуют вполне корректно, учитывая, что во втором случае используется интерфейс cgi, а в первом — нет. у php даже [опция по этому поводу есть](http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.cgi.rfc2616-headers). но вникать во все эти php-шные потроха у меня нет ни времени, ни малейшего желания.

Comment: направление для удара молотком я уже подсказал. если не получится как-нибудь наконфигурировать, можно попробовать override_function, далее — пропатчить php-fpm либо nginx.